# Clean system after 2 upgrades and update

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, powerpc, cleanup

I have power mac G5. After many attempts to install some reliable OS I was successful after following steps:

1. Install Lubuntu 12 for PowerPC
2. Upgrade to Lubuntu 14
3. Upgrade to Lubuntu 16
4. Partial Update (It could not update all)

## Questions:

**After these upgrades/updates I should have a lot of trash in my system (old packages, etc..) Is it correct?**

**If I am correct how I may clean system?**

P.S. I want to use resulting HDD image to clone 10 PowerG5-G4 PC's.

Comment: Try `sudo apt autoremove` then `sudo apt-get autoclean`  to get rid of unneeded packages, clear cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get autoclean` should get rid of all old install files.